# What happens if certain pins missing on USB 3.0 interface?

Tags: usb, pins

I have a "SanDisk Ultra Dual 32GB USB 3.0 OTG Pen Drive" and I noticed there is a broken pin in the USB A interface.

After I disassembled it turned out I missing the 2. pin on the 5 pin side what is should be the USB3's StdA_SSRX+ pin.

Tried to search for information on what happens if certain pins missing but cannot find a suitable answer.

I believe I am still able to use the Drive as USB2 device but I am not familiar with the subject so please let me know if I can use the drive as it is or should I remove some or all of the remaining pins belong to USB3 or the drive should be scraped. Soldering on a new interface is above my capability.

I know there is a micro-USB on it still, but I want to make it safe and preferably usable as not I am the only one using it.

Comment: Plug the device into a USB2 only port (or a USB2 only extension cable) and it'll work normally (assuming nothing else is broken).  Then copy your data off and get a new drive.

Comment: I don't see how this question is off-topic. The issue is in lack of information  on the sequence of attaching USB3 devices. The answer is that the USB3 attempts to connect first. If one pin is broken, the connect (via LFPS) won't be successful, and after 360ms timeout the device MUST try to connect over alternative USB2 wires. So there is no need to remove any other pins, and leave the crippled connector as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From wikipedia:

this is the USB 3.X Connections of the type A male plug:

[image: usb 3.0]

And the type 3.X type A female:

[image: usb 3.0]

D+ and D- are used for USB 2.0. All the other are used for USB 3.X.

I do now know which pin broke, but you certainly need GND pin and VCC pin. After that, you need both of D+ and D- to use USB 2.0.

Regarding USB 3.0, I am not sure which pins you can skip.

Comment: I don’t know whether backwards compatibility is strictly a requirement, but you can typically plug a USB 2 device into a USB 3 host or vice versa, so you might reasonably expect them to downgrade gracefully; if they can’t negotiate USB 3 then they fall back to USB2.

Comment: It is a male connector so I am missing the 6. pin ( StdA_SSRX+ ) updated the question as well. You know I wonder what it can cause, my initial thought was I can simply remove the other pins ( 5-9 ) and reduce the interface to a USB 2.0 but I like to get a kind of confirmation of how should I proceed.

Comment: Why don't you replace the cable/connector as a whole with a new USB 3,0 connector? Its probably less time consuming than trying to figure out all that.